# Why can't Excel update some of the links in my workbook

Tags: excel

I have a Master workbook in MS Excel that references data in 4 other workbooks.

When it opens I get the following message:

```
We can't update some of the links in your workbook right now.
You can continue without updating their values, or edit the links you think are wrong.
[Continue] [Edit Links...]
```

Each referenced workbook contains a N row, 365 column rectangular range that I have named 'DataRange'

My master workbook contains 4 lots of N row, 365 column ranges with Array Formula linked to these named ranges:

```
{='C:\Path\[Workbook1Name.xlsx]Sheet'![DataRange]}
```

It feels like i've come across an Excel bug.. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by ditching the FormulaArray and set the FormulaR1C1 for the entire range. Unfortunately the formula was a bit more complicated.

```
=INDEX(
'C:\Path\Workbook1Name.xlsx'!DataRange, 
ROW() - ROW(Workbook1DataRange) + ROW('C:\Path\Workbook1Name.xlsx'!DataRange) - 5, 
COLUMN() - COLUMN('C:\Path\Workbook1Name.xlsx'!DataRange) + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MS Excel 2013, when you receive this error?
If so, it maybe due to the "3D reference in your named DataRange" in Excel 2013 or because you're referencing a range or cell in a closed workbook.

Excel allows the defining of names that refer to specific cells or ranges of cells in that workbook, similarly (using the Define Name tool in the Formulas tab) you can assign a formula to a name and then use that name in place of the formula.

The named formula or named data range is part of a collection in that workbook's (workbook1) objects and can be used in different workbook (workbook2), but the link to the defined name in the other workbook must be done one of two ways.

1. Link the defined name with a formula like this
   ='C:\Folder\Path\Workbook1.xls'!NamedFormula or NamedDataRange
2. Or Create a defined name in workbook2 (it can have the same defined name as workbook1's or a new name) and then refer workbook2's defined name to workbook1's defined name. Select Define Name on the Formula tab and copy a link like this in the Refers To Field:
   ='C:\Folder\Path\Workbook1.xls'!NamedFormula or NamedDataRange

   - Note these links will only work when being used in simple formulas which treat the link as a direct links. It will not work with more complex formulas when the original workbook (workbook1) is closed because the link is often treated as an indirect link in complicated formulas.

To work around this issue, use either of the following methods:

1. Save workbook1 and workbook2 as .xlsb files.
2. Do not add an external reference link to a defined name that refers to a 3D reference or named range.
3. Or open both workbooks

For more detail information, please refer to the following link:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2755120

If you're still receiving an error/ warning message after trying all my above suggestion. You might want to some troubleshooting.

Try this:
 - Open Excel. Under Tools->Options->Calculation, select the Update remote
references box.
Open your workbook. Make sure the box the remote reference box is checked. Save your workbook this way after updating the link. Close workbook and Excel.Restart Excel and open your workbook. 
 - Look under defined names and delete all that you don't need or that have broken formulae. Run a FindLink search, to pin point the problem.

This process worked for one of workmates with this exact problem.

I hope this helps, if not let me know. There might be a 4th solution.

Comment: I saw the article that you've copied from. Unfortunately the work-arounds didn't work.

I don't believe that I had a 3D reference. It was a reference from one workbook to a 2D range in another workbook.

To be honest, I don't understand what a 3D range is..

Comment: Yes, I'm using Excel 2013

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue after going on a scavenger hunt. In my case, the reference was to an old file that no longer exists, and removing the reference was all that was needed. Unfortunately Excel does not pinpoint where the reference is, so it was a pain to look for the cell that was making the reference.

In my workbook, it was a reference as a part of a Data Validation. For others seeing the same error, I recommend using the Find & Select -> Go To Special feature (Home ribbon tab) then searching by Formula errors and and Data validation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Excel
2. Go to "Inquire" tab page in the ribbon
3. Select "Workbook Analysis"
4. Check Items\Cells\With Validation Criteria items. In the "Validation Text" you might spot references to the extenal source.
5. The "Cell Address" column would give you the list of problematic cells.
6. Look around any other supsicious findings of the Workbook Analysis tool

[image]

Comment: If you can't see the "Inquire" tab choose File -> Options -> Add Ins, Select "Com Add-Ins" and hit Go, then activate it. [Instructions here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-on-the-inquire-add-in-6bc668e2-f3c6-4729-8ce1-75ea20aa9d90?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (see the title). A defined name had a reference to an earlier version of my workbook that was saved with xxxxx.a.xlsx and I am now on version xxxxx.m.xlsx. Once I cleared out the reference to the old version (which was discovered by PerfectXL Risk Finder and not by any clever machinations) the message stopped.